# How to replace classes by the replaceChild

Tags: javascript, dom

In the next example I would like to replace all the yellow classes with the red class using the `replaceChild` method, but I fail in doing so. How can I do this?

```
<div id='myExample' class='yellow'>my Example</div>

<script>
        var div = document.getElementById('myExample');
        var name = div.getElementsByClassName('yellow');
        while(name.length > 0){
            name[0].parentNode.replaceChild('#red', name[0]);
        }
</script>

.yellow {
    color:yellow
}

.red {
    color:red
}
```

Comment: 'replaceChild' replaces the element, not the class.

Comment: Take a look on [**.replaceChild**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild) on **MDN**, it expects two arguments and both are DOM objects the old one and the new one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Element.classList.replace`.

```js
var yellow = document.querySelectorAll('.yellow');
for(const x of yellow) x.classList.replace("yellow", "red");
```

```css
.yellow {
    color:yellow
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id='myExample' class='yellow'>my Example</div>
```

Comment: I want to avoid classList, if possible, but i shall keep your answer if it cannot be done otherwise, since it is a correct answer. Thank you a lot, anyway.

Comment: *"I want to avoid classList"*, so how do you want to do that?!

Comment: with the replaceChild. Am I mistaken in its use ?

Comment: And why to replace the whole element with a new one only to change its class name!

Comment: In replaceChild I replace name[i], that is the name of the class. But I think you are right. As @Poul Bak remarked 'replaceChild' replaces the element, not the class. So I am doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace classes, you can simply follow this pattern:

```
var el = document.querySelector("your_element")
el.classList.replace("class_to_remove", "class_to_replace_with")
```

Edit the code according to your needs